# SVN on Eclipse still try to synchronize eclipse .settings directory despite svn:ignore flag

Tags: eclipse, svn

In my python/pydev project home directory, eclipse create 3 files/directory :

```
.settings
.project
.pydevproject
```

As I do not want to share these files, I set a svn:ignore flag on the home project directory with these 3 files/directory specified in it.

It works well for .projet and .pydevproject, but not for .settings : 
From time to time, .settings reappears into the "team synchronize perpective" as to be synchronized/committed into the svn repository.

How can I get the eclipse '.settings' definitively ignored during svn commit in eclipse gui ?

Answer (score 3):

Do you have checked in .settings before adding it to ignored? If so, you should remove it from svn (not the working copy of cause).

Comment: Yes it has been added, before setting the ignore flag. But I removed it from the repository (not the woking copy). I still have the problem.

Comment: I think Ame is correct.  It doesn't sound like you actually managed to remove what you needed from the repository.  .settings is a directory, no?  Maybe you have to remove all the contents of it from the repository before you can dig .settings directory out of there as well.

Answer (score 1):

If the `.settings` folder was previously under SVN (i.e. commited) then you should remove it from you SVN first.

If you still want to keep it in your working copy, you can do:

```
svn remove .settings --keep-local
```

in command line, and do `svn ls` (**if you see this folder listed, you haven't removed it from SVN!!!**)

If you already removed it and still have a problem you can try one of 2 things:

```
1. Deleting the folder manually (assuming no complex\unique settings were made)
   and letting Eclipse recreate it
2. Deleting only the inner folder `.svn` (only the one inside .settings),
   and then running svn cleanup (Team -> Cleanup)
```

The first one is preferred, since it is never the best idea to mess around with SVN's files.

You can (and should) exit eclipse, back this folder up, and update your working copy before this process.

Answer (score 0):

if you have installed subversive you should also install the "subversive svn jdt ignore extensions".

you will find it here:

- help > install new software ...
- select your eclipse download site. in my case its "Helios - http://download.eclipse.org/releases/helios"
- you'll find it under collaboration > Subversive SVN JDT Ignore Extensions (optional) (Incubation)

Answer (score 0):

That sounds you have sometimes added this folder under version control and checked it it. You need to first removed it (svn rm via command line or via TortoiseSVN on windows) and do a commit. This needs to be done outside from Eclipse. After you changed that you can start Eclipse again.